# Updating stageid of a Dynamics CRM entity using the OData API resulting in Invalid Cast exception

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to update the stageid of the Business process Workflow(BPF) enabled entity in attempt to move the next stage using the Odata api.

Below is my HTTP request details

```
[organization]/api/data/v8.1/MyEntity(0df630c1-3e1e-e811-810f-3863bb35ed38)
Method :- Patch

Body :-

{"stageid@odata.bind":"/processstages(0e603558-a5e2-176b-6c18-3b498377ab12)","traversedpath":"4625784d-7813-4e07-aef5-a7e3f231219f,0e603558-a5e2-176b-6c18-3b498377ab12"}
```

But, my request fails with invalid cast exception.

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E6D73AE1","innererror":{
      "message":"System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E6D73AE1","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Update(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Boolean checkForOptimisticConcurrency, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Update(Entity entity, UpdateOption updateOption)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.UpdateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, String entityKeyValue, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PatchEntity(String entityName, String key, EdmEntityObject entityDelta)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help on what i might be doing wrong here? I usually use the @odata.bind for the lookups, but stageid seems to be of type Unique identifier. how do i update a unique identifier?

Also, it would be really helpful to know how can one debug or know more details about this administrator reference numbers.

P.S:- I know updating the stageid can be achieved using the CRM SDK's, but i din't find any help doing the same with the odata API.

Answer (score 0):

Techically stageid is just a guid and not a lookup. Try to update your entity using following payload:

```
{"stageid":"0e603558-a5e2-176b-6c18-3b498377ab12"}
```

Comment: yes i tried this as a part of my trial and error attempts, but this fails too with the below error.

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the navigation property 'stageid'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.","innererror":{
      "message":"A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the navigation property 'stageid'; however, a 'StartArray ... (too long to paste complete error message)

Comment: {"stageid":"0e603558-a5e2-176b-6c18-3b498377ab12","traversedpath":"4625784d-7813-4e07-aef5-a7e3f231219f,0e603558-a5e2-176b-6c18-3b498377ab12"} this was my payload.